# Why "check-my-answer" is off topic?

Tags: discussion

Why in math.SE it is legitimate to ask questions of "proof-verification" and here one can not? what is wrong with that? and if it is not legitimate so why to tag it?

Comment: This is a different site so we have different policies. Why would you expect otherwise? (The tag is a relic.)

Comment: Since there is apparently no desire for renewed discussion among the community at this time, I'm closing as duplicate. If anyone wants to discuss current policy, please flag for reopening or post a new question.